# What does these stats tell me?

Tags: mysql, performance

I have run a test today. to see the variants for insert performance on an 
innodb table which is empty with source file having 10K records.

I used " mysql -uuname -pxxxxxx -Ddbanme < insert_file.sql "

Here are the different stats that came out.

```
    BINARY LOGGING IS ENABLED
    innodb_flush_log_trx_commit = 1     Time: 25 minutes
    innodb_flush_log_trx_commit = 2     Time: 4 seconds

    BINARY LOGGING IS DISABLED
    innodb_flush_log_trx_commit = 1     Time: 6 minutes
    innodb_flush_log_trx_commit = 2     Time: 3 seconds
```

I am not sure on what to understand from this.  Please share your thoughts on this test details.

Comment: Thanks Fenwick for making the post look better.

Comment: also you need a special hardware for setting `innodb_flush_log_trx_commit = 2` , or you may loose data on crash

Comment: Do you know the difference between `trx_commit` 1 and 2?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit) you will see that when `innodb_flush_log_trx_commit` is 1 MySQL writes to flush log more often. As you can see in the documentation, it has to be 1 in order to achieve ACID compliance. In your case, when importing data from file, if you have value 1 and something breaks, your whole transaction will fail (table will stay empty), with value of 2, if something breaks, your table will contain records that succeeded (before import failed).

Regarding `BINARY LOGGING`, when there is no binary logging your insert works faster. You don't need binary logging if you don't have slave servers and don't want to replicate commands from your master server, so you can turn it off since that will increase your performance.

Comment: I mean to know if there is any special case where when both innodb_flush is set to 1 and binary logging enabled will there be drastic slow down in performance... Which is the case here. anyways thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Your test already showed that there is difference in performance. There will be difference with any write operation you perform. Those two settings shouldn't have any performance impact on SELECTs, though.